# WPF WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, wysiwyg

I have created a wysiwyg editor as a standard C# program using the windows form control. I would like to do the same thing except with WPF.

In my old application I did something like this.

```
using mshtml;
private IHTMLDocument2 doc;

...

HTMLeditor.DocumentText =

"<html><body></body></html>"; 

doc = HTMLeditor.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2; 

doc.designMode = "On";
```

Which allowed the the use of Document.ExecCommand on the editor.

How is this accomplished in WPF? It doesn't look like the WebBrowser control in WPF allows for designmode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    editor.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(editor_Navigated);
    editor.NavigateToString("<html><body></body></html>");
}

void editor_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = editor.Document as IHTMLDocument2;

    if (doc != null)
        doc.designMode = "On";
}
```

**Edit:** where editor is a WebBrowser control.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Just a pointer to anyone who is also trying this, don't forget to add the Microsoft HTML Object Reference to your project and include mshtml!

Comment: Alternatively, you can also set contentEditable = true on the body tag and/or use InvokeScript to execute javascript on the document. This will get you away from the mshtml requirement.